# How can I fetch a row in mysql oop

Tags: php, mysql, oop, mysqli

I am making a change password function. Currently It is just changing the password. But I want to amend it a bit. If email and password is valid then it should change the password, otherwise not. This is my code. Can anyone help me?

```
function CHANGE_PASSWORD($conn, $MSG)
{
    $sql = $conn->prepare("UPDATE users SET password = ? WHERE email = ? AND password=?");
    $sql->bind_param("sss", $newpass, $email, $password);
    $email = $_REQUEST["EMAIL"];
    $pass = $_REQUEST["PASSWORD"];
    $newpass = $_REQUEST["NEW_PASSWORD"];

    if ($sql->execute()) {

        if($sql->affected_rows == 0) {
            $json["STATUS"] = "FAIL";
            $json["MESSAGE"] = "Invalid email / password";
        } else {
            $json["STATUS"] = "SUCCESS";
            $json["MESSAGE"] = "Password Update Successful";
        }               
    } else {
        $json["STATUS"] = "ERROR";
        $json["MESSAGE"] = "Please try again later.";
        $json["ERROR"] = $sql->error_list;
    }

    $sql->close();
    return json_encode($json);
    #function ends
}
```

My Current URL looks like this

> http://localhost/safespaces/server.php?REQUEST=CHANGE_PASSWORD&EMAIL=mr.aleem001%40gmail.com&PASSWORD=haioye&NEW_PASSWORD=12345

Comment: The answer you seek, is [fetch_array](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php).  See also `fetch_all`, `fetch_assoc` and others linked on that page. **Note**: that you can not fetch from an `UPDATE` or `DELETE` statement.

Comment: Thankyou let me look into it @KraangPrime

Comment: @KraangPrime it always worth to read the question body

Comment: @YourCommonSense - I read the question, and the code, assuming the two match each other -- but yes, the description inside seems to be requesting `XY` when compared to the question in the title :S

Comment: Is there an issue in the question @KraangPrime and@YourCommonSense?

Comment: it's better you use `id` as condition for your update query

Comment: @AliZia the message *I am making a change password function. Currently It is just changing the password. But I want to amend it a bit. If email and password is valid then it should change the password, otherwise not.* doesn't seem to match the question *How can I fetch a row in mysql oop*

Comment: @KraangPrime I'm sorry mate about my English skills. I want to fetch a row using email and password. If the count is 1 then it should update it. I meant that.

Comment: In that case, the [solution by Anant](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41422621/3504007) on this page nailed it.

Comment: @AliZia you should declare this variables `$sql->bind_param("sss", $newpass, $email, $password);` before calling it

Comment: @KraangPrime How can i print my query?

Comment: That I am not sure -- it's a mystery and best answer I got on that was the reason you can't export the query built is for security reasons.  You could manually build the string just to see what it is outputting by putting `echo "<textarea>UPDATE users SET password = '$newpass' WHERE email = '$email' AND password= '$pass';</textarea>"; die();` after `$newpass = $_REQUEST["NEW_PASSWORD"];` just and then try running the output directly using [Navicat](https://www.navicat.com/download/navicat-for-mysql) or whatever.

Comment: @KraangPrime I am still on it but I can't get the query right.

Comment: *If email and password is valid then it should change the password, otherwise not.* Your code is doing exactly that.

Comment: My information is correct but it says invalid info.

Comment: See, this site is to answer questions, not to make your code work. You asked how to do something. Your code is doing exactly that. Then if you're not satisfied, you should ask another question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fetch a row, use

```
$result = $sql->get_result();
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
```

I Hope it Helps

Comment: what row he shoud fetch and from where?

Comment: I didn't ask the question, did I? so ask him instead @YourCommonSense

Comment: The pople who can read only the question title but never bother with the body is a real disaster for this site.